# How to fix warnings on Windows phone 8 enviroment?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a project on windows phone 8 environment with Google contact API. I get 16 warnings, a example:

```
Referent to type "System.Net.IWebProxy" claims it is defined in c:\Program Files
(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\System.dll',
but it could not be found.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please! try to elaborate your problem so you will get more help from community.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have [.NET Framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653) installed. More info about [IWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy.aspx) can be found here. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I was installed visual studio professional 2012 and Windows Phone 8 SDK. This warning create runtime error when I debug it. This warning has created by Google.GData.Client.dll. How to tweak based on the Windows Phone 8 environment?